# How do I make an intranet sharepoint 2010 site into an external one

Tags: sharepoint-2010, external, intranet

I was just wondering how do I make a sharepoint 2010 internal site that I already have an external one, meaning it can be accessed anywhere where you have access to the internet.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from licensing issues, I think you'll have to

- enable anonymous access (in central admin and at the site collection level)
- use a publicly accessible domain name